# Use Angular 2 pages in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, ng-upgrade

Currently we have application developed in Angular 1.X but we don't want to migrate from Angular 1.X to Angular 2, Since it is very wast application it will require more effort. We want other way around . Can we use Angular 2 features within Angular 1.X Application. In future whichever pages is created should be in Angular 2 but need to be worked side by side with Angular 1.X .. Like calling new route or new component from Angular 2 from Angular 1.X. Please let me know whether its possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: This may help you - https://medium.com/@SevenLee/configuration-tips-to-build-hybrid-angular-1-and-angular-2-project-in-real-world-230b715629dc

Comment: And this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688124/using-angular-2-components-in-angular-1-app-without-upgrade-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. What you are looking for is an Angular Hybrid app. Here's an [article](https://medium.com/@SevenLee/configuration-tips-to-build-hybrid-angular-1-and-angular-2-project-in-real-world-230b715629dc) to help with what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use the new angular components/modules in a legacy angular application (downgrading) or you can use legacy components in the a new angular application (upgrading).

There is a section on the angular webpage describing all this. Direct link is here
https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angular-components-from-angularjs-code